# Show that the minimal polynomial is equal to the product $(t-\alpha_1)\cdots(t-\alpha_r)$ $\ldots$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

[image: The Exercise is from the book Linear Algebra- Serga Lang, and the solution is from Rami Shakarchi]

The Exercise is from the book Linear Algebra- Serge Lang, and the solution is from Rami Shakarchi.

I have no idea how to approach the exercise in the book that’s why I had to look for the solutions manual but I don’t fully understand the solution either.

In the solution Rami states that if $\mu(t)=(t-\alpha_1)\cdots(t-\alpha_r)$ then $\mu(A)=O$ But I don’t see how this is true because if I substitute in the given equation I get a matrix $A-\alpha_i$( which would be the associated matrix with the linear map) but that subtraction cannot be made because the eigenvalue is just a scalar.

The other part I don’t fully understand is the part when $(BDB^{-1})^n=BD^nB^{-1}$. I think that given the unitary matrices $B, B^{-1}$ if $n$ Is even, then they become $1$ And if $n$ Is odd then they’ll stay the same as the solution states. But I’m not sure about this. I really appreciate any help.

Note. I already solved the exercise in the next image:
[image]

Comment: Evaluating $t-a$ with a matrix $A$ means $A-a1\!\!1$, where $1\!\!1$ is the identity matrix

Comment: Just want to point out that there's no need for the matrix $B$ in the solution. Just choose a basis in which $A$ is diagonal and you have a diagonal matrix.

Comment: And one should write something like $[A]_{\mathcal B} = D$ not $A = D$ since $A$ is not a matrix and $D$ is not a linear map.

Comment: Thank you guys, I really appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When substituting a linear transformation [matrix] in a polynomial, the constant term is interpreted as the multiple of the identity transformation [matrix].
2. $B$ needs not be unitary, only invertible. We have
   $$(BDB^{-1})^n=(BDB^{-1})(BDB^{-1})\dots (BDB^{-1})=BD^nB^{-1}\,.$$

Comment: Thank you, your answer is very clear.

Comment: I’m sorry for asking again, but even with your first answer I don’t see how $\mu(A)=0$. I thought I understood because given and eigenvector $v$ We can have $Av=\alpha_i v$ But in the example the identity matrix is not an eigenvector like I first thought and then obtain the $0$ Answer. Could you help me a little more?

Comment: Note that $A-\alpha_i I$ commutes with $A-\alpha_j I$, and for each $v$ of the eigenbasis, we have $(A-\alpha_i I)v=0$ for its eigenvalue $\alpha_i$, hence $\mu(A)v=0$.